# Connecting using 32 bit drivers on a 64 bit system in a vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbscript, which connects to a .mdb file using 32 bit drivers and it works fine on a 32 bit system, but when i try to run the same on  a 64 bit system( with 32 bit office),the connection doesnt work.
I cant install 64 bit drivers as the system has 32 bit office.
Is it possible to connect to .mdb file using 32 bit drivers on a 64 bit system?

Comment: This may be of interest : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/09/18/running-32bit-dependent-scripts-in-a-64bit-world.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, just make sure that the process executing your script is running on 32 bit.

You could try to call your script from the x86 PowerShell prompt to test it on your x64 system.

Comment: is it not possible to execute the script from any location and still connect using the 32bit drivers?the script is standalone, so i cannot ensure for it to run from 32/64 bit platform.

Comment: The bit-nes of the process executing your script will determine the bit-nes of the (database) driver it will try to use. If you want to ensure that your script is always executed in a 32 bit context you'll probably need a batch script to start your vbscript - but I'd have to search around how to do this.